# why we need the eval command in redis, if redis is single-threaded?

Tags: redis

One way to execute commands in REDIS, is via the EVAL script.

> Redis uses the same Lua interpreter to run all the commands. Also
>   Redis guarantees that a script is executed in an atomic way: no other
>   script or Redis command will be executed while a script is being
>   executed.

Since redis is single threaded, why do we need EVAL to offer atomicity? I would expect that this is implied by the one running thread.

Am I missing something? Apologies if my question is pretty simple, I am quite new to redis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis uses a single thread to execute commands from many different clients. So if you want a *group of commands* from one client to be executed in sequence, you need a way to direct Redis to do that. That's what `EVAL` is for. Without it, Redis could interleave the execution of commands from other clients in with yours.

Answer (score 3):

Every (data path) command in Redis is indeed atomic. `EVAL` allows you to compose an "atomic" command with a script that can include many Redis commands, not to mention control structures and some other utilities that are helpful to implement server-side logic. To achieve the similar "atomicity" of multiple commands you can also use `MULTI/EXEC` blocks (i.e. [transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions)) by the way.

Without an `EVAL` or a `MULTI/EXEC` block, your commands will run one after another, but other clients' commands may interleave between them. Using a script or transaction eliminates that.